# Python Syntactical error could be the indent?

Tags: python

When I am trying to run this script I am getting this error:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

I checked some similar questions and the doc, yet no success. And while the error is clear enough I haven't been able to figure it out. Apparently I am missing something.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import re

dirpath = 'path\\to\\dir'
filenames = os.listdir(dirpath)
nb = 0

open('path\\to\\dir\\file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        nb = nb+1
        print fname
        print nb
        currentfile = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)

open(currentfile) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)
```

**Edit:** Since i removed the `with` from `open` the message error changed to:

```
`open (C:\\path\\to\\\\file.txt, 'w') as outfile` :
```

> SyntaxError : invalid syntax with a pointer underneath as

**Edit:** Much confusion with this question. After all, i restored `with` and i fixed the indents a bit. And it is working just fine!

Comment: If you want to use `as`, `with` is a must. `with` can bring you much convinece so don't remove it.

Comment: oh i see. Although isn't `with` regularly used for something like `with codecs.open` ? Whats the point of keeping it if i am not using anything else. Anyway, i will restore it for later on, just in case.

Comment: `with ... as` is a syntax in Python. It acts as context manager. You have to.

Comment: i did and apparently the problem was lying elsewhere. anyhow thanks for  the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `outfile` is at the same level as `infile` - which means at the end of the first `with` block, `outfile` is closed, so can't be written to. Indent your `infile` block to be *inside* your `infile` block.

```
with open('output', 'w') as outfile:
    for a in b:
        with open('input') as infile:
        ...
    ...
```

You can simplify your code here by using the `fileinput` module, and making the code clearer and less prone to wrong results:

```
import fileinput
from contextlib import closing
import os

with closing(fileinput.input(os.listdir(dirpath))) as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the context manager `with` which means the file will be closed when you exit the with scope. So the `outfile` is apparently closed when you use it.

```
with open('path\\to\\dir\\file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        nb = nb + 1
        print fname
        print nb

        currentfile = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
        with open(currentfile) as infile: 
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: sorry you are right i will edit my question asap and update the error

Comment: No sorry is need. Learn something is the most important.@LDN-5602